# Цикл for в C# и его работа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему при использовании цикла `for` если его записать

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Instantiate(Boxprefab, new Vector3(i, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    Instantiate(Boxprefab, new Vector3(0, 0, j), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

У меня создается 3 куба по (X) и 3 куба по (Z).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я пропишу `for` таким образом

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        Instantiate(Boxprefab, new Vector3(i, 0, j), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

То есть цикл в цикле, то он создаст мне квадрат.

`for` прописывал в `void Start()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что должно получиться? получилось 9 кубов. что ожидалось?

Comment: Почему получается 9 кубов когда я пишу цикл в цикле. Если напишу два for отдельно, то он выстроит 3 по X и 3 по Z.

Comment: а сколько должно быть? 3 умножить на 3 сколько будет?

Comment: Человек уже написал более развернутый ответ. Я не так давно учу C#, и хочу разобраться более детально. Я и сам понимал что происходит умножение, но я не понимал почему. Можете больше ничего не писать, уже разобрались.

Comment: для этого C# знать не обязательно. это просто логика и математика. для школьников

Comment: Вы не увидели что я вам написал? Меня не интересует математическая составляющая данного процесса.

Comment: Что такое "математическая составляющая процесса"? Это какой-то набор слов.... А для понимания вывода инфы нужно просто знания из школы, листок бумаги и карандаш/ручка, т.к. вопрос никоим образом не относится к C#

Comment: Листок бумаги не объясняет работу написанного скрипта. Если вы не поняли ключевую составляющую вопроса, то я нечем не помогу. Я написал вопрос, чтобы получить развернутый ответ. Вы его предоставить не смогли. Человек ниже, описал все доступным языком. Если вам хочется поспорить, то это явно не ко мне. Рекомендую так же ознакомиться с нормами поведения на ресурсе - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct. По моему мнению вы слишком токсичны и высокомерны.

Comment: Это ваше субъективное мнение обиженного человека, который не смог с помощью ручки нарисовать три строки и три столбца и посчитать количество клеток. А при указании на это сильно обиделись. Научитесь мыслить без кода и писать алгоритмы на листочке, а потом обижайтесь..... Ключевая составляющая вопроса "почему так происходит". Для ответа на него нужно то, что я уже указывал и плюс немного мышления.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае циклы существуют отдельно друг от друга и сначала создаются кубы, расходящиеся по оси x, а после этого независимо от первого цикла создаётся ещё три куба на оси z. Получается 6 кубов

```
[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2]
```

Во втором случае цикл, который создаёт кубы на оси z является вложенным в первый цикл и вызывается внутри него каждый раз, когда наступает следующая итерация первого цикла. В итоге получается, что в каждой итерации базового цикла происходит по три итерации вложенного. Создаются кубы:

```
[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0], 
[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], 
[2, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Вы лучший. Спасибо за такое детальное объяснение. Я вам очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что второй цикл запускается на каждую итерацию первого цикла. Поэтому и получаем: [1,1], [1,2], [1,3] (затем снова, но уже с i=2) [2,1], [2,2], [2,3] и так далее но с i = 3